# Exclude Link from a list if it matches the URL of current website

Tags: php, list, url

I have created a php file that has a list of SEO links on them which is hosted on my server. All of my clients web pages have a resource page which includes this page and displays my links. I did this to make adding links to all of my pages easier for me. Now what I'm trying to do is write a code that would search through my links and not display the ones that are for the current site being visited.

Ex: I am on the webpage (**www.loonytoons.com**) and I want my list to display all links except the one for this page. It would have to do it for all of my clients. This following is an example of my list. Thanks

```
<ul id="resources">
    <li><a href="http://www.loonytoons.com/">Loony Toons</a> I want this link to show up on all sites execpt current site</li>
    <li><a href="http://www.theaustinbusinesslawyer.com/">Austin Business Lawyer</a> The Austin Business Lawyer Michael Pruneda can help you with any business related issues or concerns.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: perhaps show an example of the a couple lines from your php file?

Comment: store the list in either a db or an array.

Answer (score 2):

```
// isset required for win servers (This may not work on all win servers)
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])){$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];}
if (strpos($link, $domain) === false){echo $link;}
```

$link is the string of your anchor info, so you would need to store all of the links most likely in an array and put the above into a foreach loop like this:

```
foreach ($linksarray as $link) {
    // Above code would go here
}
```

In response to the bottom comment:
You could but that would be more work (you'd need strpos loops to create that array. It would be easier to just set up an array and have the array print your

's.

```
// [][0] = URL, [][1] = Title, [][2] = Description
$linkarray = array(
    array('http://url1.com', 'URL1 Title', 'URL2 Description'),
    array('http://url2.com', 'URL2 Title', 'URL2 Description'),
);
```

The only thing you would need to change is in the first code box in my original answer change all $link to $link[0] (not in the foreach())

Then your final line would look something like:

```
if (strpos($link[0], $domain) === false){
    echo '<li class="liclass"><a href="'. $link[0] . '">' . $link[1] . '</a> - ' . $link[2];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Serj ! is there any way that I could make it automatically add new links when I add a new li?

Comment: You could but that would be more work (you'd need strpos loops to create those arrays. It would be easier to just set up an array and have the array print your <li>'s s

Comment: Thanks @serj thats awesome! I havent been able to try it out yet as I have been busy on other projects but I'll definitely give it a shot. Thanks for your help

Comment: I am getting a syntax error where you echo the final line. I've been trying to figure it out but couldn't. I would really appreciate your help

Comment: Ahh crap, yeah, '</a>' - should be '</a> - ',  I fixed it above.

Answer (score 0):

On the client side, you could use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to hide links for the current URL:

```
$('a[href=' + document.URL + ']').hide();
```